# Cannot snapshot Openstreetmap in leaflet using savewidget/webshot

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, htmlwidgets

I have the need to make a snapshot of a userdefined map using openstreet map in leaflet. I am using saveWidget to save a html file and then webshot to take a snap of that file. It works perfectly with Esri.WorldStreetMap and others. However, I cannot make it work with Openstreetmap. Below is a minimal exaple:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button", "An action button")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button,
               {
                 themap<-leaflet() %>%
                   addProviderTiles("Openstreetmap.Mapnik")%>%
                   setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852,zoom=14)%>% 
                   addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
                 saveWidget(themap, 'temp.html', selfcontained = T)    
                 webshot('temp.html', file = "map.png",cliprect = viewport")
               })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

With minor modifications your code works on my R 3.4.2:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("button", "An action button")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button,
               {
                 themap <- leaflet() %>%
                   addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
                   setView(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852,zoom=14) %>% 
                   addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
                 saveWidget(themap, 'temp.html', selfcontained = T)    
                 webshot('temp.html', file = "map.png",cliprect = "viewport")
               })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: The Problem persists under R 3.4.2 ( i was using 3.4.1. before). I have the same problem on my local version and on the Rstudio server and shiny server.  I don't see the minor modifications to the code that you mentioned.

Comment: thanks. spelling error when posting. Unfortunately i still experience the problem.

Comment: R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

....

Comment: attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] htmlwidgets_0.9 webshot_0.4.2   leaflet_1.1.0   shiny_1.0.5    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13    digest_0.6.12   mime_0.5        R6_2.2.2    xtable_1.8-2    jsonlite_1.5    magrittr_1.5    tools_3.4.2    
 [9] crosstalk_1.0.0 httpuv_1.3.5    yaml_2.1.14     rsconnect_0.8.5 compiler_3.4.2  htmltools_0.3.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157997/discussion-between-mette-laegdsmand-and-marco-sandri).

Comment: If anyone experience the same and find a solution plaese let me know.

Comment: 1. the modified code above worked for me. 2. there are two spelling error in your code: Openstreetmap -> OpenStreetmap, viewport" - "viewport". How can you have spelling errors? How that code work for yourself? 3. why do you need the shiny part for example? It makes no sense. The script inside the {} part can be run independently.

Comment: @dracodoc Hi. I totally agree with your comment. I do not understand why Mette said that my code did not work. If my modified code works for you, could you upvote it ? Thank you !

Comment: @dracodoc Thank you!